# array como condicion en un while (JS)

Tags: javascript

no entiendo porque me estaria dando como true lo siguiente y cualquier cosa que escriba tambien:

```
let amigos = ["Juan", "Pepe", "Jorge", "Francisco", "Juan"] 
let intento=prompt("nombre?")

while (intento!=amigos) {
    alert("Sería bueno tener un amigo que se llame Juan")

    intento=prompt("diga el nombre devuelta")
}
alert("Tengo un amigo que se llama Juan")
```

Comment: Sería complicado que esto: `while (intento!=amigos) {` andara ¿no?, lo digo por que tratas de buscas la diferencia entre un string y un array de strings, **tal vez** debas mirar **el uso de includes**, tal vez

Comment: no sería `amigos.IndexOf(intento)>-1` algo más correcto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El caso es que estas comparando un `string` directamente con el `array`, no con cada elemento del `array`, para lograr esto puedes usar uno de estos métodos:

**Solución con el método [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)**:

Esta es la solución mas rápida y sencilla(especialmente en Chrome) donde el método `includes()` recibe como parametro un elemento y si este elemento existe dentro de la lista devolverá true, en caso contrario false. En cuanto a tu codigo:

```
let amigos = ["Juan", "Pepe", "Jorge", "Francisco", "Juan"] 
let intento=prompt("nombre?")
while (!amigos.includes(intento)) { //si intento no se encuentra en la lista amigos continua el bucle
    alert("Sería bueno tener un amigo que se llame Juan");

    intento=prompt("diga el nombre devuelta");
}
alert("Tengo un amigo que se llama Juan");
```

**Solución con el método [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)**:

Este método recibe como parámetro un elemento y si se encuentra en la lista devolverá el index, en caso contrario devolverá -1, para implementarlo como solución se puede usar como `indexOf(x)<0` para que de un valor booleano:

```
let amigos = ["Juan", "Pepe", "Jorge", "Francisco", "Juan"] 
let intento=prompt("nombre?")
while (amigos.indexOf(intento)<0) { //si al buscar el indice del nombre y es menor que 0, es decir, no se encuentra, continua con el bucle
    alert("Sería bueno tener un amigo que se llame Juan")

    intento=prompt("diga el nombre devuelta")
}
alert("Tengo un amigo que se llama Juan")
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que en lugar de

```
while (intento!=amigos) {
```

sería

```
while (!amigos.includes(intento))
```

Comment: Buenas !!! Vengo a comentarte que no te desanimes si tu respuesta no fue aceptada directamente. Mira la otra, y fíjate como ha respondido, da detalles, información, que esta bien y mal. Mucha suerte !!!